# How to check the size of all files inside a directory and empty it if it is exceeding certain size

Tags: bash

I am a bit new to the bash scripting and have a scenario on which i need to know the efficient way to complete.
I need to check the size of all the files inside a directory and if the size of any files exceeds certain limit i need to empty those files and then send email to a mail ID with details like name of the files which are emptied, the original size, the current size after emptying.
Found lots of blog on the same topic but just wanted to check the most efficient way i can complete the above scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu No I do not have a logrotate scenario.I just need to empty the files.No backup is required for those files.After emptying the files i need to send the emails based on the condition mentioned above.

Comment: **rotate** *count* -- `If count is 0, old versions are removed rather then rotated.`      **mail** *address* -- `When a log is rotated out-of-existence, it is mailed to address.`   **size** *size* -- `Log files are rotated when they grow bigger then size bytes`. Also check **create** / **copytruncate**.

Comment: BTW, I'm not the down-voter on your question, but my guess is they were expecting the question to be more specific; and include something about what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able complete the above scenario with the help of find command.

```
rm -f logFile*
find . -type f -size +20k -exec du -sh {} \; >> logFile.txt
cat logFile*
find . -type f -size +20k -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```